# IO error table on cppreference.com (C++)

Tags: c++, io

I'm referring to a manual about [std::basic_ios::operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) on cppreference.com.

Does anyone know what each row means in this table?

[image]

Comment: As it says, each row is one possible combination of flags.

Comment: I'm confused. For example, what does the first row (line) of 'operator bool' mean? (which says true).

Comment: @Toshihiro It means that if `good()` returns `true` and `fail()`, `bad()`, `eof()` returns `false`, then `operator bool` returns `true` (conversion operator).

Comment: @Toshihiro `operator bool` is a member function technically, same as `good()`, `fail()`... With it a basic_ios object could be converted to `bool` with value the table lists.

Comment: @Holt , songyuanyao Thank you. I come to understand!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three state flags: `eofbit`, `failbit`, `badbit` that can be set under different conditions, each of which can have two states: `true` or `false`. For example `eofbit` gets set when the file has reached end of file. This allows you to see that `while(cin >> x) { ... }` [using `operator bool` implictly] will work until you have one of `failbit` or `badbit` set - but `eofbit` itself will still allow another loop, which is what you want.

The resulting `operator bool` and `operator!`, as well the state other accessors such as `good()`, `fail()` etc will be reporting different things depending on these states.

So, for each row in the table, you have a given set of state flags values, and the outcome for each of the accessors.

Answer (score 2):

This table says which results returned by the `good()`, `fail()`, `bad()` and `eof()` methods and by the `operator bool` and `operator !` depending on the values of the `eofbit`, `failbit` and `badbit` flags (i.e. depending on the state of the stream).